# Will this wait until previous run completes before running again?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
public void doSomething() { ... }
```

Just wanna make sure this doesn't spin up another run if the previous one doesn't complete in time?

If not, how to make this the case?

I tested with Thread.sleep() and it SEEMS like it's waiting but not sure. I just want to confirm this.

If this means it is only running one at a time does it wait and then immediately run after the previous completes? Or does it skip the run and wait until the next scheduled time when none are running?

Comment: on unix, you could check if the process is sleeping, i.e. using the command top -ef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` to execute `cron` tasks when no task schduler configured.
Tasks configured by `@Scheduled` will executed in a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with single thread.
`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` use a `DelayQueue` to schedule tasks.

So, default behavior is tasks will running as serial. It will not skip the run until the task ended. And the next scheduled time is uncertain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I do like that it is not going to run them concurrently, that's definitely a no-no for me. I'm not sure that I like that the next scheduled time is uncertain though, will figure out exactly what I want.

Comment: @Wes ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduling is based on relative time. The next scheduled time affectd by the task execution, so the task start may be unprecise. We can optimize our task or customize task scheudler to avoid this.